# finding the mean and standard deviation of randomly answering questions correctly

Tags: probability, statistics

2 students each write the same multiple choice test. The test has 5 questions, and each question has 5 answers (exactly one of which is right). The students answer the questions randomly.

What is the probability that they both get the same number of answers correct? (ANSWER: 0.3198)

What is the probability that their papers are identical, assuming that they have answered independently of one another? (ANSWER: 0.00032)

For the first part I tried taking the joint probability of X=Y

For the second part I took the total number of ways to answer 5 questions (3125) and put that under 1 (1/3125)

Does my reasoning make sense?

Comment: Thanks for showing your work. Simulation result agrees with your approach to first part: In R, Code
`set.seed(2020); x = rbinom(10^6, 5, 1/5); y = rbinom(10^6, 5, 1/5); mean(x==y)` returns $0.319459,$ which is in satisfactory agreement with your answer.// Second part also seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning for the second part is correct.  The idea is to observe that, no matter what the first student answers, the second student has to match their answers exactly, and this is only possible if for each question, they choose the same answer as the first student.  Since for a single question that happens with probability $1/5$, for all five, it is $1/5^5 = 1/3125$.

The first part only requires that they get the same number of questions correct.  This is given by the sum $$\sum_{k=0}^5 \left( \binom{5}{k} (1/5)^k (1 - 1/5)^{5-k} \right)^2 = \frac{3122577}{9765625} \approx 0.319752.$$